# Trocar div de lugar com jquery

Tags: jquery, div

Digamos que eu tenha um `div` mãe, e dentro dessa `div` tenho outras 3. E um Botão.

```
<div id="mae">
    <div id="a" class="child"></div>
    <div id="b" class="child"></div>
    <div id="c" class="child"></div>
</div>

<button id="Trocar">Trocar Div</div>
```

Gostaria então que ao clicar no botão, as divs trocassem de posição! Na verdade gostaria que a primeira div, fosse para em ultimo, e a div seguinte assumisse a primeira posição! E assim sucessivamente!

```
Ex :: Cliquei uma vez
    <div id="mae">        
        <div id="b" class="child"></div>
        <div id="c" class="child"></div>
        <div id="a" class="child"></div>
    </div>

Ex :: Cliquei duas vezes
    <div id="mae">
        <div id="c" class="child"></div>
        <div id="a" class="child"></div>
        <div id="b" class="child"></div>
    </div>

Ex :: Cliquei três vezes
    <div id="mae">        
        <div id="a" class="child"></div>
        <div id="b" class="child"></div>
        <div id="c" class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

Como pode ver! O ciclo volta a se repetir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#Trocar').click(function() {
    $('#mae div:first-child').remove().insertAfter($("#mae div:last"));
});
```

Exemplo completo:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    $('#Trocar').click(function() {
        $('#mae div:first-child').remove().insertAfter($("#mae div:last"));
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mae">
    <div id="a" class="child">a</div>
    <div id="b" class="child">b</div>
    <div id="c" class="child">c</div>
</div>

<button id="Trocar">Trocar Div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#Trocar').click(function() {
   $('#mae div:first-child').appendTo($('#mae'));
});
```